# Connecting to remote MySQL database from local LAMP through a university proxy

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, proxy

I have LAMP set up on my laptop for working on a web app for a project at university.

If I have the web app connect to a local MySQL database, all is fine and the app connects to the database.

However, if I specify a remote database, the app will load for a while before displaying this error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect
>   to MySQL server on '176.32.230.14' (110) in
>   /home/ben/site/inc/db.php on line 2 
>   Connect Error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on '176.32.230.14' (110)

and stops at this section of code:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

The remote database connection only fails when I am at my university connected to the WiFi and proxy.

I believe the proxy is the likely cause for my problem.

So, do I need to set up Apache to some how connect to the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey to me it sounds like you are probably unable to connect out on the mysql port (3306).

Comment: Ah yes, the error code 2003 does indicate that. This might mean I will have no way of connecting to the remote database while at university, if the proxy is blocking port 3306.

Comment: yup something along those lines. you would need a VPN connection or something similar I believe a proxy would just work on port 80 or 443.